# jqgrid restore row is not working

Tags: jqgrid, restore

I am debugging some old code (joy) and the issue is that restoreRow is not working at all so when the user clicks on the rows (it goes into edit mode), but the user doesn't change anything and then moves on to the next row, the prev row remains in edit, rather than being restores. I am at loss why this happens, so any insight would be welcome

```
//at the beginning of the file
    var currentRowIdSelected;
    var prevRowIdSelected;
    var prevRowModified = false;


 $(grid).jqGrid({
            url: als.common.getServerPath() + 'SamplesDefinitionAjax/SamplesDefinition',
            editurl: als.common.getServerPath() + 'SamplesDefinitionAjax/UpdateSample',
            datatype: 'local',
            mtype: 'POST',
            height: 516,
            width: 1000,
            caption: 'Samples',
            hidegrid: false,
            loadonce: true,
            loadtext: 'Please wait,</br>loading samples...',
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ClientBarcode', label: 'Client Barcode', sortable: false, width: 46 },
                {
                    name: 'OrderNumber',
                    index: 'OrderNumber',
                    label: 'Seq #',
                    sortable: true, sorttype: 'integer',
                    width: 28
                },
                {
                    name: 'Description',
                    label: 'Description',
                    sortable: false,
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validateDescription }
                },
                {
                    name: 'Type',
                    index: 'Type',
                    label: 'Type',
                    sortable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'select',
                    width: 40,
                    align: 'center',
                    editoptions: {
                        dataUrl: als.common.getServerPath() + 'SamplesDefinitionAjax/GetTypes',
                        buildSelect: function (data) {
                            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                            var s = '<select id="samplestypefororder">';
                            if (response && response.length) {
                                s += '<option value="" disabled="disabled" ></option>';
                                $.each(response, function (index, elem) {
                                    if ((elem.Tier === "1") || (elem.Tier === "N")) {
                                        s += '<option data-tier="' + elem.Tier + '" value="' + elem.Type + '">' + elem.Type + '</option>';
                                    }
                                });
                                s += '<optgroup label="Not Counted"><options>';
                                $.each(response, function (index, elem) {
                                    if (elem.Tier === "Z") {
                                        s += '<option data-tier="' + elem.Tier + '" data-parentTier="' + elem.parentTier + '" data-parentType="' + elem.parentType + '">' + elem.Type + '</option>';
                                    }
                                });
                                s += '</options></optgroup><optgroup label="Other">';
                                $.each(response, function (index, elem) {
                                    if ((elem.Tier === "2") || (elem.Tier === "B") || (elem.Tier === "S") || (elem.Tier === "D")) {
                                        s += '<option data-tier="' + elem.Tier + '" data-parentTier="' + elem.parentTier + '" data-parentType="' + elem.parentType + '">' + elem.Type + '</option>';
                                    }
                                });
                                s += '</optgroup>';
                                s += "</select>";
                                sampleTypesExcludedFromDup.length = 0;
                                $.each(response, function (index, elem) {
                                    if (elem.Tier === "N") {
                                        sampleTypesExcludedFromDup.push(elem.type);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            return s + "</select>";
                        },
                        dataEvents: [
                            { type: 'change', data: { test: 12 }, fn: sampletypechanged }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                { name: 'SampType', label: 'SampType', sortable: false, editable: false, hidden: true, width: 50 },
                {
                    name: 'ReceivedWeight',
                    index: 'ReceivedWeight',
                    label: 'Received Weight',
                    sortable: true, sorttype: 'number',
                    editable: false, width: 32, align: 'right'
                },
                { name: 'ReceivedDate', label: 'Received Date', sortable: false, editable: false, width: 40, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'SecurityTag', label: 'Security Tag', sortable: false, editable: true, width: 30 },
                { name: 'OriginalWorkorder', label: 'Original Workorder', sortable: false, editable: false, width: 60, hidden: true },
                { name: 'ClientStdName', label: 'Standard Name', sortable: false, editable: false, width: 40, hidden: false },
                { name: 'ClientStdType', label: 'Standard Type', sortable: false, editable: false, width: 30, hidden: true },
                { name: 'ParentOrderNumber', label: 'Duplicate #', sortable: false, editable: false, width: 50, hidden: false },
                { name: 'ParentSampDesc', label: 'Duplicate', sortable: false, editable: false, width: 30, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasChildRef', label: 'HasChildRef', sortable: false, editable: false, width: 30, hidden: true },
                { name: 'Status', label: 'Status', sortable: false, editable: false, width: 30, hidden: true }
            ],
            multiselect: true,
            multiboxonly: true,
            pager: pager,
            pgbuttons: false,
            pginput: false,
            rowNum: -1,
            rowattr: function (data) {
                if (data.Status === 'Cancel') {
                    return { "class": "sampleCancelRow" };
                } else return {};
            },
            loadComplete: function () {
                var samples = $(grid).jqGrid('getRowData');
                checkBarCodeMismatch(samples);

                currentRowIdSelected = undefined;
                prevRowIdSelected = undefined;
                prevRowModified = false;

                $('input#total_number_of_samples').trigger('notify.updateWoSampleCount');

                // update the col number when click on a edit box. 
                $(grid).off('click', 'input[name="Description"]');
                $(grid).off('click', 'input[name="SecurityTag"]');
                $(grid).off('click', 'select[name="Type"]');
                $(grid).on('click', 'input[name="Description"]', function () {
                    curCol = colnumSampdesc;
                });
                $(grid).on('click', 'input[name="SecurityTag"]', function () {
                    curCol = colnumSecuritytag;
                });
                $(grid).on('click', 'select[name="Type"]', function () {
                    curCol = colnumSampletype;
                });


            },
            onCellSelect: function (row, col) {
                curCol = col;
            },
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                // this is common to multiple grids and could go in a grid library
                if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey) {
                    $(this).jqGrid('resetSelection');
                }
                else if (e.shiftKey) {
                    var initialRowSelect = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    $(this).jqGrid('resetSelection');

                    var currentSelectIndex = $(this).jqGrid('getInd', rowid);
                    var initialSelectIndex = $(this).jqGrid('getInd', initialRowSelect);
                    var startId;
                    var endId;
                    if (currentSelectIndex > initialSelectIndex) {
                        startId = initialRowSelect;
                        endId = rowid;
                    }
                    else {
                        startId = rowid;
                        endId = initialRowSelect;
                    }

                    var shouldSelectRow = false;
                    $.each($(this).getDataIDs(), function (_, id) {
                        if ((shouldSelectRow = id === startId || shouldSelectRow) && (id !== rowid)) {
                            $('#flagGrid').jqGrid('setSelection', id, false);
                        }
                        return id !== endId;
                    });
                }
                return true;
            },
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                currentRowIdSelected = id;

                woOrdno = $(grid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                compPrevSampType = $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + currentRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumSampletype).text();

                if (prevRowIdSelected !== undefined) {

                    //$(grid).jqGrid('restoreRow', prevRowIdSelected);
                    //$(grid).restoreRow(prevRowIdSelected);

                   if (prevRowModified) {
                        //validate description
                        var descCellText = $("#" + prevRowIdSelected + "_Description", grid).val();
                        var test = [];
                        if (descCellText !== undefined) {
                            test = validateDescription(descCellText, 'Description');
                        } else { // the row was not in edit mode (user pressed entered before selecting new row)
                            descCellText = $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + prevRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumSampdesc).text();
                            test = validateDescription(descCellText, 'Description', 1);
                        }

                        if (!test[0]) {
                            showErrorDialog(descCellText + ' ' + test[1]);
                            $(grid).resetSelection();
                            $(grid).setSelection(prevRowIdSelected, false);
                            return true;
                        }

                        //client barcode
                        var clientBarcodeCellText = $("#" + prevRowIdSelected + "_ClientBarcode", grid).val();

                        if (clientBarcodeCellText === undefined) {
                            clientBarcodeCellText = $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + prevRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumClientBarcode).text();
                        }

                        $(grid).saveRow(prevRowIdSelected, {
                            url: als.common.getServerPath() + 'SamplesDefinitionAjax/UpdateSample',
                            extraparam: {
                                folderno: webview.workorder.woheader.model.woheader_folderno,
                                rowid: prevRowIdSelected,
                                ClientStdName: $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + prevRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumClientstdname).text(),
                                ClientStdType: $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + prevRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumClientStdType).text(),
                                ParentOrderNumber: $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + prevRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumParentordernumber).text()
                            },
                            aftersavefunc: function () {
                                if (!reloadAfterSave(prevRowIdSelected)) {
                                    var samples = $(grid).jqGrid('getRowData');
                                    checkBarCodeMismatch(samples);
                                }
                            },
                            successfunc: function () {
                                if (reloadAfterSave(prevRowIdSelected)) {
                                    reloadSampleDefinitions(webview.workorder.woheader.model.woheader_folderno);
                                }
                                else
                                prevRowModified = false;
                                return true;
                            },
                            errorfunc: function (rowid, response) {
                                $('<div>').html(response.responseText.split('\"')[3].split('\\')[0].substr(11))
                                .dialog({
                                    modal: true, title: 'Server error',
                                    buttons: { Close: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        //TODO: revisit this
                        //  $(grid).restoreRow(prevRowIdSelected);
                    } else {
                        $(grid).restoreRow(prevRowIdSelected);
                    }
                }

                var samplestatus = $(grid).getCell(currentRowIdSelected, 'Status');
                if (samplestatus === 'Cancel') {
                    prevRowIdSelected = undefined;
                    return false;
                }

                $(grid).setColProp('Type', { editable: true });
                $(grid).setColProp('SecurityTag', { editable: true });

                var currentSampType = $(grid).getCell(currentRowIdSelected, 'SampType');
                var currentType = $(grid).getCell(currentRowIdSelected, 'Type');
                var currentOriginalWorkorder = $(grid).getCell(currentRowIdSelected, 'OriginalWorkorder');

                if (currentSampType === 'PDU') {
                    $('#woEditSamplesErrormsg').text('You can not modify the PDU samples directly but you can delete them.');
                    $(editsampleserrordlg).dialog('open');
                    return true;
                //} //else if (currentOriginalWorkorder !== '' && currentType && currentType.substring(0, 4).toUpperCase() !== 'PULP') {
                  //  $('#woEditSamplesErrormsg').text('You can not modify these samples as this is a child workorder but you can delete them.');
                  //  $(editsampleserrordlg).dialog('open');
                  //  return true;
                } else if (currentOriginalWorkorder !== '') {
                    $(grid).setColProp('Type', { editable: false });
                    $(grid).setColProp('SecurityTag', { editable: false });
                }

                if (compPrevSampType === 'Composite') {
                    $(grid).setColProp('ClientBarcode', { editable: true/*, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validateClientBarcode }*/ });
                }
                else {
                    $(grid).setColProp('ClientBarcode', { editable: false });
                }

                $(grid).editRow(currentRowIdSelected, {
                    keys: true,
                    successfunc: function () {
                        if (reloadAfterSave(currentRowIdSelected))
                            reloadSampleDefinitions(webview.workorder.woheader.model.woheader_folderno);
                        return true;
                    },
                    aftersavefunc: function () {
                        if (!reloadAfterSave(prevRowIdSelected)) {
                            var samples = $(grid).jqGrid('getRowData');
                            checkBarCodeMismatch(samples);
                        }
                    },
                    url: als.common.getServerPath() + 'SamplesDefinitionAjax/UpdateSample',
                    extraparam: {
                        folderno: webview.workorder.woheader.model.woheader_folderno,
                        rowid: currentRowIdSelected,
                        ClientStdName: $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + currentRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumClientstdname).text(),
                        ClientStdType: $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + prevRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumClientStdType).text(),
                        ParentOrderNumber: $(grid).find(' tr[id="' + currentRowIdSelected + '"]').find("td").eq(colnumParentordernumber).text()
                    },
                    restoreAfterError: false,
                    mtype: "POST",
                    errorfunc: function (rowid, response) {
                        $('<div>').html(response.responseText.split('\"')[3].split('\\')[0].substr(11))
                        .dialog({
                            modal: true, title: 'Server error',
                            buttons: { Close: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } }
                        });
                    }
                });

                prevRowIdSelected = currentRowIdSelected;

                if (id === '000') {
                    $("#" + id + "_Description", grid).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $("#" + id + "_SecurityTag", grid).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
                return id;
            }
        })
            .navGrid(pager,
                {
                    addtitle: 'Add sample',
                    addfunc: function () { addSample(); },
                    edit: false,
                    deltitle: 'Delete samples',
                    delfunc: function () { delSamples(); },
                    search: false,
                    refresh: false
                },
                //edit
                {},
                //add
                {},
                //delete
                {},
                //search
                {},
                //view
                 {})
            .closest('div.ui-jqgrid-view').children('div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar').css('text-align', 'center').
                children('span.ui-jqgrid-title').css('float', 'none');

        $(grid).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', pager, {
            buttonicon: 'ui-icon-copy-code',
            caption: '',
            title: 'Copy sample description from client barcode',
            id: 'btnCopyCode',
            onClickButton: copySampleDescToBarcode
        });

        $(grid).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', pager, {
            buttonicon: 'ui-icon-copy-desc',
            caption: '',
            title: 'Copy sample description from other workorder',
            id: 'btnCopyDesc',
            onClickButton: openWorkordersDialogBox
        });     

        $(grid).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', pager, {
            buttonicon: 'ui-icon-clipboard',
            caption: '',
            title: 'Paste column from clipboard',
            id: 'btnPaste',
            onClickButton: pasteClipboard
        })
            .navSeparatorAdd(pager, { sepclass: 'ui-separator', sepcontent: '' });
        $(grid).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', pager, {
            buttonicon: 'none',
            caption: btnBarcodeMisMatchCaptionFilter,
            id: 'btnMismatches',
            onClickButton: filterMismatches
        })
            .navSeparatorAdd(pager, { sepclass: 'ui-separator', sepcontent: '' });


        $(grid).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', pager, {
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-gedit-sample-type",
            caption: "",
            title: "Group edit sample type",
            id: "btnGroupEditSampleType",
            onClickButton: groupEditSampleType
        });

    };
```

If you look in the code, the last statement (if the row hasn't been modified, restore it) does not work. I traced it and the code does go there, hits it but the row does not get restored.

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use?** The code which you posted don't contains any call of `editRow`. The variables `currentRowIdSelected`, `prevRowIdSelected` and `prevRowModified` are not declared and not initialized. So It's really difficult to understand what the code should do.

Comment: Oleg, I am using v 4.4.1 in this project. Will update the code in the question body shortly. Thank you!

Comment: code updated, sorry - it's quite long!

Comment: I am in vocation now. I'll come back in two weeks.

Comment: have fun but sadly I need the answer soon - would be nice if more people answered jqgrid questions